# Autofill new content fields with previously created content

Tags: 7, entities

Gotta question that I bet has been done, but I cannot find a solution. :)

I have content types called POC (Points of Contact). The POC type has basic personal info like: first name, last name, address, phone number, fax, and email address. There are about 600 of those nodes.

Now, I have a form that users need to fillout and they will need to enter the names of their manager (using autocomplet widget with entity reference), hr rep, and administrator...all who are part of the POC nodes.

I would like for the users who fill out the form to use an auto-complete field for the name of each POC and the rest of that POC data to autofill the other required fields about that POC in the form.

Basically an autofill of POC data.